# It's just too meta: [duplicates] should have [no-duplicates]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, burninate-request

There are currently 6186 questions tagged [duplicates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/duplicates), but also 75 tagged [no-duplicates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/no-duplicates). Most of the questions tagged [duplicates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/duplicates) seem to be about avoiding or deleting duplicates anyway, so there isn't much point in also having the [no-duplicates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/no-duplicates) tag.
Besides, whether you want to use or discard duplicates once you've identified them, doesn't change the problem of identifying them, which is what the questions are really about.

Comment: burnination or (oddly enough) synonym?

Comment: Duplicate duplicate tags. So *meta*.

Comment: @ryanyuyu Marking [no-duplicates] as a synonym of [duplicates] somehow just feels... wrong.

Comment: @m69 yeah, it's pretty janky.  A general retag (or closure) would be the correct action.  But if we're lazy, then the synonym would work.

Comment: I remember that at one time the tag [duplicates] was used to signify that the question is a duplicate, but you don't remember of what... apparently it is still alive since those days...